# EF Core 3 With Pomelo MySQL Provider Does Not Scaffold Views

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

According to the following link, EF Core 3 supports reverse engineering views:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/

And according to these links, there isn't yet a MySQL provider for EF Core 3:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/17556
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html

So, I used the Pomelo provider to scaffold:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=server;user=user;password=password;database=database" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -OutputDir EF -f
```

But scaffolding did not create the views. Are you also experiencing this issue or is this something related to my configuration?

Comment: perhaps give link to the `Pomelo` provider?

Comment: Are you using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` 3.0.0-rc1.final? v2.2.0 is not compatible with EF Core 3.0.

Comment: BTW, your best bet for getting help with this problem is opening an issue at https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

Comment: I am using "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.0.0-rc1.final"

Comment: I test it with "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.0.0-rc1.final" and get the same result as yours, it does **NOT** scaffold types for views for me.

Comment: Issue being tracked at [Pomelo MySQL Provider Does Not Scaffold Views](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/867).